# How to show set of Arrays in one <TD> in Spring Boot / JSP?

Tags: spring-boot, jsp, jstl

I would like to show all the right answers(Green) in one TD if there are more than one and all the wrong answers(Red) in one TD if there are more than one. Is there anyway in the controller or at the front end that I can achieve this?
With my current code this is what I get.

[image]

The aim is to display like this
[image]

Controller

```
    @GetMapping("/quesInAss/{id}")
    public String quesInAssessment(@PathVariable("id") Integer id, Model model, HttpSession session) {

        Integer insId = (Integer) session.getAttribute("instId");
        List<Answers> rlist = new ArrayList<Answers>();
        List<Answers> wlist = new ArrayList<Answers>();

        Assessments ass = as.getAllByAssInst(id, insId);
        model.addAttribute("assName", ass.getAssName());

        List<Questions> queslist = qs.getQuesByAssessment(ass);
        for (Questions ques : queslist) {
            List<Answers> anslist = ansService.getAnswersByQuestion(ques);
            for (Answers answer : anslist) {
                if (answer.getAnsStatusCode().equals("CORR")) {
                    rlist.add(answer);
                    Answers[] array = new Answers[rlist.size()];
                    array = rlist.toArray(array);
                    model.addAttribute("rightAnsList", array);                  
                } else {
                    wlist.add(answer);
                    Answers[] array = new Answers[wlist.size()];
                    array = wlist.toArray(array);
                    model.addAttribute("wrongAnsList", array);
                }
            } 
        }
        model.addAttribute("queslist", queslist);
        return "listOfQuesInAss";
    }
```

JSP

```
    <c:forEach items="${queslist}" var="ques">
        <tr>
            <td>${ques.quesText}</td>
            
            <c:forEach items="${rightAnsList}" var="rightans">
                <c:if test="${rightans.questions.quesId == ques.quesId}">
                    <td>${rightans.answer}</td>
                </c:if>
            </c:forEach>
            <c:forEach items="${wrongAnsList}" var="wrongans">
                <c:if test="${wrongans.questions.quesId == ques.quesId}">
                    <td>${wrongans.answer}</td>
                </c:if>
            </c:forEach>
        </tr>
    </c:forEach>
```

Comment: Thanks Swati for your reply, adding colors to them isn't the aim I want them in one <td> correct ones in one <td> and the wrong ones in one <td>

Comment: Why do you change the ArrayList into an Array? Working with JSTL and ArrayList is a bit easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if I could understand your question right, try this:

```
<c:forEach items="${queslist}" var="ques">
    <tr>
        <td>${ques.quesText}</td>
         <td>
           <c:forEach items="${rightAnsList}" var="rightans" varStatus="status">
            <c:if test="${rightans.questions.quesId == ques.quesId}">
               ${rightans.answer}
            </c:if>
            <c:if test="${not status.last}">,</c:if>
           </c:forEach>
        </td>
        <td>
          <c:forEach items="${wrongAnsList}" var="wrongans" varStatus="status">
            <c:if test="${wrongans.questions.quesId == ques.quesId}">
                ${wrongans.answer}
            </c:if>
            <c:if test="${not status.last}">,</c:if>
          </c:forEach>
        </td>
    </tr>
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: I'm getting this Exception:-   java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "last"

Comment: Because I don't have a running enviroment for jstl, can you try `varStatus="status"`by adding it to forEach and using `${not status.last}`?